# Gitlab CI Android accepting license returns error

Tags: android, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run functional tests on gitlab runner in docker, like described [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/). But the command `android` is deprecated and now we must use `sdkmanager` instead. Here is my `.yml`:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
  - unzip sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip

  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --verbose "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;google;google_play_services"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"
  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager "sources;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"

  - yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/tools
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/tools
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/tools/platform-tools/
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
```

If I run it, I see in logs:

```
$ yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --verbose "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
Info: Parsing legacy package: /builds/git/proj/android-app/tools
Info: Parsing /builds/git/proj/android-app/tools/package.xml
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
License android-sdk-license:
---------------------------------------
Terms and Conditions
...//Whole license
Accept? (y/N): Info: Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)".
Info: "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" ready.
Info: Finishing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)"
Info: Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /builds/git/proj/android-app/build-tools/26.0.2
Info: "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" complete.
Info: "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" finished.
done
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

An error without explanation. If I try to set install commands with `echo y | ...` rather than `yes | ...` they install all fine, but later I get the error, that the licenses are not accepted. Then I insert the command:

```
- yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

and it gives me the same error without explanation:

```
Accept? (y/N): All SDK package licenses accepted
done
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have no idea why it ends with error and gives me no explanation what happened.

EDIT: After many attempts I conclude, that every command containing `- yes | ...` returns unexplained error. If I set `- echo y | ...` instead of `- yes | ...` I get later when building app:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
BUILD FAILED in 45s
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you exclude any following commands throwing errors?

Comment: @StefanvanGastel I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

This looks like docker image issue.

Simple workaround:

```
- yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses || true
```

Comment: I was getting "All SDK package licenses accepted" & "ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1" (in Docker).
This worked for me, thanks!